# Ejecutar build de proyecto react en servidor remoto

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de crear una pagina react y de cargarla a un servidor pero no completo, si no que solo la version de produccion del proyecto.

He cargado los archivos al servidor pero no muestra contenido y genera errores js que no tienen sentido real.

Tampoco me es posible ejecutar las funciones de npm como seria start o run build, ya que no hay mas funciones.

Tengo instalado node en su versión 16 y npm en su versión 8.

Comment: Npm run build. Lo que te deja esta instruccion en la carpeta build lo pones en el middleware de archivos estaticos de tu servidor

Comment: ¿Que servidor estás usando? ¿Es una maquina remota administrada por ti? ¿Usas apache, nginx, IIS...? ¿Cómo estás "cargando" los archivos al servidor?